# ApiGateway is not routing the api call

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

`My Apigateway application is not routing the api calls to the necessary apis. Below is the application.properties and pom.xml of the api gateway application

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DyUJ.png)
[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGQJp.png)

When I try to call the product api using ApiGateway's port,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0h6f.png)

and in console only this weight attribute is showing up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8sF.png)`

`So in conclusion I'm not able to call the micrservice via apigateway **but it can be called by explicitly writing down the port number where the microservice is created**. Please help me in solving this issue. I'll add below the parent project's dependencies`

[parent application's pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd237.png)

Comment: Sorry that I added images only . I'm new here and I was unable to add the code as it was showing some indentation error. Sorry !!

Comment: I have also tried using the gateway dependency without mvc. But it is still not routing

Comment: Solved the issue by replacing the dependency to 

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
 </dependency>

and adding the following in the application.properties

 spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true